# AMCL without using odomedry (but laser_scan_matcher instead)

Tags: ros, localization, navigation, amcl, laser-scan-matcher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I have been trying to localize my robot using only an URG Hokuyo (so without any odometer) on a known static map. I have been able to run laser_scan_matcher to simulate odometry with gmapping to build the map. Now, using this map I'd like to use amcl to localize my robot in it but it doesn't seem to work since the laser data are not trying to fit the map...

**$rviz:**
[Image1](http://img6.imageshack.us/img6/5191/screenshotat20120321151.png)

**$rxgraph:**
[Image2](http://img828.imageshack.us/img828/7399/screenshotat20120321152.png)

**$tf_monitor:**
RESULTS: for all Frames
Frames:
Frame: /base_link published by /laser_scan_matcher_node
Average Delay: -0.00268532 Max
Delay: 0.00239109
Frame: /laser published by /base_link_to_laser Average Delay: -0.039569 Max Delay: 0
Frame: /odom published by /amcl Average Delay: -0.0978399 Max Delay: 0
All Broadcasters:
Node: /amcl 10.3673 Hz, Average Delay: -0.0978399 Max Delay: 0
Node: /base_link_to_laser 25.2033 Hz, Average Delay: -0.039569 Max Delay: 0
Node: /laser_scan_matcher_node 10.3616 Hz, Average Delay: -0.00268532 Max Delay: 0.00239109

**$roslaunch:**

```
<launch>

  <param name="/use_sim_time" value="false"/>


  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_link_to_laser" 
    args="0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 /base_link /laser 40" />

  <node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" name="rviz" 
    args="-d $(find laser_scan_matcher)/demo_amcl.vcg"/>

  <node name="hokuyo" pkg="hokuyo_node" type="hokuyo_node" respawn="false" output="screen">
    <param name="calibrate_time" type="bool" value="false"/> 
    <param name="port" type="string" value="/dev/ttyACM0"/> 
    <param name="intensity" type="bool" value="false"/>
  </node>

  <node pkg="laser_scan_matcher" type="laser_scan_matcher_node" 
    name="laser_scan_matcher_node" output="screen">
    <param name="fixed_frame" value = "odom"/>
    <param name="use_alpha_beta" value="true"/>
    <param name="max_iterations" value="10"/>
  </node>

 <node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="/home/neutri/maps/map1.yaml"/>

  <node pkg="amcl" type="amcl" name="amcl" output="screen" >
  <!-- Publish scans from best pose at a max of 10 Hz -->
  <param name="odom_model_type" value="diff"/>
  <param name="odom_alpha5" value="0.1"/>
  <param name="transform_tolerance" value="0.2" />
  <param name="gui_publish_rate" value="10.0"/>
  <param name="laser_max_beams" value="30"/>
  <param name="min_particles" value="500"/>
  <param name="max_particles" value="5000"/>
  <param name="kld_err" value="0.05"/>
  <param name="kld_z" value="0.99"/>
  <param name="odom_alpha1" value="0.2"/>
  <param name="odom_alpha2" value="0.2"/>
  <!-- translation std dev, m -->
  <param name="odom_alpha3" value="0.8"/>
  <param name="odom_alpha4" value="0.2"/>
  <param name="laser_z_hit" value="0.5"/>
  <param name="laser_z_short" value="0.05"/>
  <param name="laser_z_max" value="0.05"/>
  <param name="laser_z_rand" value="0.5"/>
  <param name="laser_sigma_hit" value="0.2"/>
  <param name="laser_lambda_short" value="0.1"/>
  <param name="laser_lambda_short" value="0.1"/>
  <param name="laser_model_type" value="likelihood_field"/>
  <!-- <param name="laser_model_type" value="beam"/> -->
  <param name="laser_likelihood_max_dist" value="2.0"/>
  <param name="update_min_d" value="0.2"/>
  <param name="update_min_a" value="0.5"/>
  <param name="odom_frame_id" value="odom"/>

  <param name="base_frame_id" type="str" value="base_link" />
  <param name="global_frame_id" type="str" value="map" />

  <param name="resample_interval" value="1"/>
  <param name="transform_tolerance" value="0.1"/>
  <param name="recovery_alpha_slow" value="0.0"/>
  <param name="recovery_alpha_fast" value="0.0"/>
  <param name="use_map_topic" value="true" />
  <param name="first_map_only" value="true" />
</node>

</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30124/amcl-without-using-odomedry-(but-laser_scan_matcher-instead)/) by [N3UTR1NOS](https://answers.ros.org/users/2020/n3utr1nos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-03-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You'll have to work with odom_alpha parameters and simply try out what works best for you. You might also want to try [hector_slam](http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_slam).

---

Originally posted by [Cav](https://answers.ros.org/users/1633/cav/) with karma: 345 on 2012-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mksun](https://answers.ros.org/users/25181/mksun/) on 2015-11-25**:
hello,can hector_slam locate the robot in a known map with amcl? how did you load the map? can you please share the lauch file?